# How to increase and decrease CPU usage on a EC2 instances with Ubuntu 18.04 and Python programming?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

This is the current code I am using, changing the range from 3000 to 85000 in the while loop my computer could experience CPU_usage from 7% to 95%.

I have been trying to adapt other algorithms or python libraries but they saturate the CPU_usage.

The main idea of this test is to check how quickly the EC2 instance reacts in case of high CPU_usage or low CPU_usage. Additionally, I want to change the CPU_usage every 5 to 10 minutes. In other words, every 5 minutes will have different CPU_usage which will be from 5% to 95%.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from time import sleep
import random
import schedule

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    print('worker ', i)
    x = 0
    y = random.randint(20000, 85000)
    while x < y:
        a= random.random()
        b = x * a
        print(b)
        x += 1
    l.release()
    sleep(1)


def process_A():
    lock = Lock()
    for num in range(10000):
        pro = Process(target=f, args=(lock, num))
        pro.start()
        sleep(0.3)
        return pro

    
def proc_stop(p_to_stop):
    p_to_stop.terminate()
    print ("after Termination")

while True:

    p = process_A()

    p

    print("to sleep")

    sleep(10)

    print("to stop")

    p.terminate()

    sleep(2)
    
    p = process_A()
    
    p

    print("working")
```